# Cross table delete with mysql

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

When I execute the following query:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta 
    WHERE post_id 
        NOT IN (
            SELECT post_id 
            FROM wp_postmeta a 
            INNER JOIN wp_sl_posts b 
            ON a.post_id = b.id
            )
```

I get an error message:

```
You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause
```

I sort of know why, but I really don't know the syntax required here to perform the operation.  I've tried a few different alternatives based on answers here and elsewhere, but not luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
DELETE wp_postmeta 
FROM wp_postmeta 
left outer JOIN wp_sl_posts b ON a.post_id = b.id
WHERE b.post_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same, and should work:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_sl_posts)
```